# Magento 1.4.2 - Make Registration Fields Not Required

Tags: magento

I have tried a very commonly used method to make the telephone field not required during registration, but it doesn't seem to work with Magento 1.4.2

I've made a copy of

> magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

to

> magento/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

and removed the following code from the validate function in that file

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
$errors[] = $helper->__('Please enter telephone.');
```

}

I have also removed the

```
class="input-text required-entry"
```

from the register.phtml file, but I can't get past the validation. I keep getting the error

> "Telephone" is a required value.
>   "Telephone" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default telephone attribute is set to required in the database. See `is_required` column of `eav_attribute` table, search for `attribute_code = 'telephone'`.

Alternatively you can run this code just once, such as with an install script.

```
$telephone = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
           ->loadByCode('customer_address', 'telephone')
           ->setIsRequired(false)
           ->save();
```

Also you have to remove the asterisk * from the from in you template `checkout\onepage\billing.phtml`

Change (Line ~120) from

```
<label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
```

to

```
<label for="billing:telephone"><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
```

Delete cache to view changes.

Comment: I second this method. The install script should be placed in your own plugin directory in your company's namespace so that it's reproduceable across other installs (say, if you move servers, hosting, or promote code to staging/production)

Comment: thanks guys! Worked perfectly. I was initially wary of editing the database, but if that's the only way, then cool.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few steps to take (version 1.7.0.2).

1. As mentioned above: change database table `eav_attribute`. `Phpmyadmin` is one easy way to do that.
2. Comment out these 3 lines:

   ```
   if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
           $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the telephone number.');
   }
   ```

   in files:

   - `App/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php`
   - `includes/src/Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract.php`
   - `includes/src/_checkout.php`
3. You can also remove the `*` in the `register.phtml` and `billing.phtml` files in the onepage folders of the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent` and `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer` folders.

Make no mistake, Magento REALLY wanted to make that a required entry!

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of all the suggested solutions of copying and editing core-files but this will be upgrade-suicide.

For now (Magento 1.9 and older) the only method that does not require modifying Magento core files is to use a dummy value for the telephone field.

A simple mock-up solution is to add to the bottom of the 'address/edit.phtml' file:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#form-validate').submit(function(){
        var telephone = $('#telephone');
        if( !telephone.val().length )
            telephone.val("<?= $this->__('Not supplied') ?>");
    });
});
```